# Querying database and putting two columns of each row into an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql database with table "profile_values" (yes, it's a Drupal db), and I would like to pull the user's name, title and company id with one query. (I have done this in the past with three queries, but I'd like to do it in one.)

```
|   fid   |    uid    |    value

|    4    |    100    |     john
|    8    |    100    |     doe
|    9    |    100    | web developer
|   22    |    100    |   D3239GE77
```

I used different field id's (fid) to show that there can be field id's between the rows that I want to pull, but the field id will not change, so 4 will always be first name, 8 would be last name, 9 would be title, and 22 would be company id.

MY FIRST ATTEMPT:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM profile_values WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY fid ASC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $userinfo[] = $row['value'];

            $firstname = $userinfo[0];
            $lastname = $userinfo[1];
            $title = $userinfo[10];
            $companyid = $userinfo[12];

        }
```

But this method won't work, because, depending on the optional fields that users will have filled out, there may be more or less fields between.

**I need a way to say, "In this array, if fid = 4, $firstname = value**

Comment: First of all, you're only selecting one column in your query.

Comment: I know. It worked for that example. I don't know how I would put them together for what I want to do - that is assigning the value to a variable (such as firstname) based upon the fid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fid, uid, value FROM profile_values WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY fid ASC");
$user = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    switch ($row['fid']) {
    case 4:
        $key = 'firstname';
        break;
    case 8:
        $key = 'lastname';
        break;
    case 9:
        $key = 'title';
        break;
    case 22:
        $key = 'company_id';
        break;
    default:
        continue 2; // 2 required when using switch inside loop
    }

    $user[$key] = $row['value'];
}
```

Comment: I read through your solution and the other, and having used switch before, this made perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that do not require a `switch` statements or `if`s. It's based on an array where you previously map the table's `fid`s to the keys on your destination array:

```
$fieldMap = array(
    4 => 'firstname',
    8 => 'lastname',
    9 => 'title',
    22 => 'companyid'
);
$userinfo = array();
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT fid, value 
    FROM profile_values 
    WHERE uid = $uid 
    ORDER BY fid ASC
");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $fieldKey = $fieldMap[$row['fid']];
    $userinfo[$fieldKey] = $row['value'];
}
```

Below is my original suggestion, where we pivot the results to get a "regular" table format, instead of a property table format:

```
SELECT 
    p1.value AS first_name,
    p2.value AS last_name,
    p3.value AS title,
    p4.value AS company_id
FROM profile_values p1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_values p2
    ON p2.uid = p1.uid 
    AND p2.fid = 8
    LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_values p3
    ON p3.uid = p1.uid 
    AND p3.fid = 9
    LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_values p4
    ON p4.uid = p1.uid 
    AND p4.fid = 22
WHERE p1.uid = $uid AND p1.fid = 4
```

This is more expensive for SQL then the way you're currently doing it, but it will allow you to fetch data from multiple users more easily (just change `p1.uid = $uid` to, e.g., `p1.uid IN (2, 6, 29)`.

Comment: Any advantage over switch? I used the other because I understood it more clearly.

Comment: Just a little shorter, and I personally find `switch` somewhat clumsy. If you have 15 fields instead of 4, this will look way cleaner. But it's a matter of personal choice, stick with `switch` if it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fid, value FROM profile_values WHERE uid = '$uid' ORDER BY fid ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    switch ((int)$row['fid']) {
        case 4:
            $firstname = $row['value'];
            break;
        case 8:
            $lastname = $row['value'];
            break;
        case 9:
            $title = $row['value'];
            break;
        case 22:
            $companyid = $row['value'];
            break;
    }
}
```

Then, I would be using `isset()` to check whether the variables exists, e.g. `isset($lastname)`

Hope this helps